# Installing Warp (Simulator): make: *** No rule to make target 'install3'. Stop

Tags: software-installation, anaconda

I am following the Anaconda installation documentation for Warp (https://warp.lbl.gov/how-tos/installation/anaconda-installation). I have followed the steps up until the `Makefile.local3` step where I wrote `FCOMP = /usr/bin/gfortran` `FCOMPEXEC =` instead of the steps on the page because I am using my system default gfortran compiler. However, when I try to proceed to the next step `make -j install3`, the error `make: *** No rule to make target 'install3'.  Stop.` How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular software, but errors of that type often occur when the `make` command is executed from the wrong directory

Comment: Hmm. Well I am in the /home/username/warp directory, and I am pretty sure that is correct. Any other ideas?